# how to not update column if value is not present sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a customer table which consist few columns along with `password` column in sequelize mysql

When I edit/update the customer if the user doesn't provide the password in the request it should not update the password column at all (should remain untouched).

**How can I accomplish such program inside the customer schema page?**

I am using following method to update the table:

```
db.customers.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.body.id
    }
}).then(data => {
    data.update({
        cash_credit: req.body.cash_credit,
        name: req.body.name,
        address: req.body.address,
        state_id: req.body.state_id,
        gstin: req.body.gstin,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        email: req.body.email,
        form_type: req.body.form_type,
        pincode: req.body.pincode,
        password: req.body.password, // omit
        city_id: req.body.city_id,
        country: req.body.country || 0,
        id: req.body.id
    }).then(data2 => {
        console.log(data2);
    });
});
```

**Here is my customer schema:**

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const customers = sequelize.define("customers", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            field: "SupplierCode"
        },
        customer_type: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        cash_credit: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },

        ...

    }, {
        hooks: {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            beforeValidate: function (value, option) {
                value.zip = parseInt(value.dataValues.zip);
            },
            beforeCreate: async (schema) => {
                let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(schema.password, saltRounds);
                schema.password = hashedPassword;
                console.log(schema.password);
            },
            beforeUpdate: async (schema) => {
                if (schema.password) {
                    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(schema.password, saltRounds);
                    schema.password = hashedPassword;
                }
            }
        },
        timestamps: false,
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: {
                exclude: ["password"]
            }
        },
        scopes: {
            withPassword: {
                attributes: {
                    include: ["password"]
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember Sequelize won't update a field that you have not provided. So if the `password` is not defined, just don't pass it to the `update` call.

```
const updateData = {
    cash_credit: req.body.cash_credit,
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    state_id: req.body.state_id,
    gstin: req.body.gstin,
    mobile: req.body.mobile,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    email: req.body.email,
    form_type: req.body.form_type,
    pincode: req.body.pincode,
    city_id: req.body.city_id,
    country: req.body.country || 0,
    id: req.body.id
}

if (req.body.password) {
   updateData.password = req.body.password;
}

data.update(updateData).then(console.log);
```

Comment: that's neat, but what if I want to add this in the customer schema, is there any way?

Comment: Well you may try to add this check in the `beforeUpdate` hook. e.g. `if (shema.password === undefined) { delete shema.password}`

Comment: Well, then the first one is the only way to do the trick. To comply with DRY you may define a custom method on your Schema that will handle the update with `password` lookup.